boost subgraph giving 'forming reference to void' error
I am trying to create a boost::subgraph of a boost::adjacency_list, and I'm getting an error on creation that I do not understand.  Similar code exclusively using the boost::adjacency_list builds and works just fine.
The line creating base_graph is sufficient for the error, but the rest demonstrates how I've been using the adjacency_list on its own, and thereby how I expect to use the subgraph.
Sample code:
struct Component { int vert_id; };
struct Connection { int edge_id; };
struct NetworkData { int graph_id; };

boost::subgraph<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData>> base_graph;

auto& sub_graph = base_graph.create_subgraph();

base_graph[boost::graph_bundle].graph_id;
sub_graph[boost::graph_bundle].graph_id;

const auto base_vert = boost::add_vertex(base_graph);
const auto sub_vert = boost::add_vertex(sub_graph);
base_graph[base_vert].vert_id;
base_graph[sub_vert].vert_id;
sub_graph[base_vert].vert_id;
sub_graph[sub_vert].vert_id;

const auto [base_edge, a1] = boost::add_edge(base_vert, sub_vert, base_graph);
const auto [sub_edge, a2] = boost::add_edge(base_vert, sub_vert, sub_graph);
base_graph[base_edge].edge_id;
base_graph[sub_edge].edge_id;
sub_graph[base_edge].edge_id;
sub_graph[sub_edge].edge_id;

Error log:
In file included from /.../include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:255,
                 from /.../main.cpp:1:
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::detail::adj_list_any_edge_pmap::bind_<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData>, Connection, boost::edge_index_t>’:
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2801:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::adj_list_choose_edge_pmap<boost::edge_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData>, Connection>’
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2809:16:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::adj_list_edge_property_selector::bind_<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData>, Connection, boost::edge_index_t>’
/.../include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:218:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::edge_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData>, boost::edge_index_t>’
/.../include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:234:8:   required from ‘struct boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData>, boost::edge_index_t, void>’
/.../include/boost/graph/subgraph.hpp:351:64:   required from ‘class boost::subgraph<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Component, Connection, NetworkData> >’
/.../main.cpp:46:122:   required from here
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2764:33: error: forming reference to void
 2764 |             typedef value_type& reference;
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2765:39: error: forming reference to void
 2765 |             typedef const value_type& const_reference;
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2770:17: error: forming reference to void
 2770 |                 type;
      |                 ^~~~
/.../include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2774:17: error: forming reference to void
 2774 |                 const_type;
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~

vert_id, edge_id and graph_id are all notional to demonstrate how I anticipate accessing node/edge data.
I have figured out that if I change Connection to boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, std::size_t> it will build. But this prevents access to the graph_bundle, as well as makes access to edge properties less convenient, and I don't know how to use boost::property.
I've also reviewed this SO question and this SO question but they do not use subgraph, and my issue appears to be related to subgraph particularly.
I get similar errors using GCC13 and MSVC.

On godbolt, both gcc and clang give a very different error: error: no type named 'is_directed_t' in 'struct Connection'.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Another case of copy-paste hurried questions, I guess

I had tried to use another graph type (edge_list, I think) that required a different set of template parameters, and forgot to correct them when copying from my editor.  Thanks for correcting that.

Subgraph requires vertex_index as well as edge_index: doc

A graph type modeling VertexMutableGraph and EdgeMutableGraph. Also the graph must have internal vertex_index and edge_index properties. The vertex indices must be maintained automatically by the graph, whereas the edge indices will be assigned by the subgraph class implementation.

The simplest way to automatically advertise this property is to use the internal property tag instead of your bundle type:
// struct Connection { int edge_id; };
using Connection = boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int>;

Indeed, with some modifications, here's the thing working:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>

struct Component {
    int vert_id;
};

#ifndef CUSTOM_PROPERTY_MAPS
    using Connection = boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int>;
#else
    struct Connection {
        int edge_id;
    };
#endif

struct NetworkData {
    int graph_id;
};

using G   = boost::adjacency_list<                //
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, //
    Component,                                  //
    Connection,                                 //
    NetworkData                                 //
    >;
using Sub = boost::subgraph<G>;

int main() {
    Sub base_graph;

    auto& sub_graph = base_graph.create_subgraph();

    get_property(base_graph).graph_id;
    get_property(sub_graph).graph_id;

    auto const base_vert = add_vertex(base_graph);
    auto const sub_vert  = add_vertex(sub_graph);
    base_graph[base_vert].vert_id;
    base_graph[sub_vert].vert_id;
    sub_graph[base_vert].vert_id;
    sub_graph[sub_vert].vert_id;

    auto const [base_edge, a1] = add_edge(base_vert, sub_vert, base_graph);
    auto const [sub_edge, a2]  = add_edge(base_vert, sub_vert, sub_graph);

#ifndef CUSTOM_PROPERTY_MAPS
    auto bmi = get(boost::edge_index, base_graph);
    auto smi = get(boost::edge_index, sub_graph);
    bmi[base_edge];
    smi[sub_edge];
#else
    base_graph[base_edge].edge_id;
    // base_graph[sub_edge].edge_id; // UB!?
    // sub_graph[base_edge].edge_id; // UB!?
    sub_graph[sub_edge].edge_id;
#endif
}

If You Insist
You might insist on bundled properties. In that case you have to tweak the required traits to tell subgraph about the edge index:
namespace Lib {
    struct Component   { int vert_id;     };
    struct Connection  { int edge_id = 0; };
    struct NetworkData { int graph_id;    };

    using G = boost::adjacency_list<                //
        boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, //
        Component,                                  //
        Connection,                                 //
        NetworkData                                 //
        >;

} // namespace Lib

template <>
struct boost::property_map<Lib::G, boost::edge_index_t>
    : boost::property_map<Lib::G, decltype(&Lib::Connection::edge_id)> {};

namespace Lib {
    // ADL accessible
    static inline auto get(boost::edge_index_t, G const& g) { return boost::get(&Connection::edge_id, g); }
    static inline auto get(boost::edge_index_t, G& g) { return boost::get(&Connection::edge_id, g); }

    using Sub = boost::subgraph<G>;
} // namespace Lib

See it Live On Coliru as well

Your citation and code examples look very promising!  Thank you for taking a look.  I don't have time to try it out tonight, and will assess it sometime tomorrow.  I may have simply not understood what I was reading in the documentation.

I have tested both solutions, and they're working nicely just as I'd like them too.  I have much more to learn about how it works, and what the documentation is saying, but I appreciate the jumping off point.
